In Laravel how to get old checkbox value during reloads on a edit form in this case?
Situation:

There is an EDIT FORM with an checkbox, and other inputs.
On the database the boolean value regarding this checkbox is 1.
The code for the checkbox in the form is the following:

<input type="checkbox" name="commerce" value="1"
    {{ old('commerce', $company->commerce) ? 'checked' : '' }} />
<label>Commerce</label>

The edit form renders with the checkbox checked as expected. After this:

The user deletes the content of an string form field required by FormRequest.
The user unchecks the checkbox.
The user sends the form.

The form reloads because that emptied string field is required. But...

Despite the user had unchecked the checkbox before sending the form, the checkbox now renders checked again.

It's easy to undestand that once the checkbox is unchecked, the "commerce" parameter is not passed with the form. So old("commerce") does return anything. Then the default value is used: the value on the database ($company->commerce) that is equal to 1.
In this case, where the value is 1 (true) on the database, how can I make the user option of letting the checkbox unchecked prevail during reloads ?
Thank you,
Márcio

you are correct in understanding what is happening ... before the checkbox put a hidden input with the same name and give it a value of 0 ... now 0 will be submitted for that input if the checkbox is not checked

@lagbox thank you. The following code before the checkbox input did the trick:


The problem here is that when you don't check a checkbox in your form before submission, then the old() helper doesn't recognize it at all instead of recognizing it as unchecked. So to Laravel it's a null value, and that's why it always sets the state of the checkbox as the value of the $company->commerce field.
A suggested solution would be to add a check whether the value returned by old('commerce') is null or not:
<input type="checkbox" name="commerce" value="1" {{ !is_null(old('commerce')) && old('commerce', $company->commerce) ? "checked" : "" }}/>

Or you can even make it a little bit tidier using the @checked() directive:
<input type="checkbox" name="commerce" value="1" @checked(!is_null(old('commerce')) && old('commerce', $company->commerce))/>


Eyad, I've tested you code but the checkbox always start unchecked, independent of the value on the database.
